# i can not upload image php everything is ok but it failes uploading

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, image-uploading

everything is ok i can seperately insert query into my database but it does not move the uploaded file
here is my code. see please if you can find any issue below.

it checked my image folder directory it is correct the directory takes me to the exact folder.
upload_file is also on in php.ini
but still it is not working.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "HERE_IS_MYCORRECT_PASSWORD", "HERE_IS_MYCORRECT_DTABASE_NAME");
if($conn) {

echo "<p style='color:green;'>connected</p>";
}
else {
    echo " connection failed";
}
if(isset($_POST['uploadfilesub'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
    $filetmpname = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
    $folder = './Resources/style/images/' . $filename;
    echo "<p>".$filename."</p>";
    echo "<p>".$filetmpname."</p>";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product_images VALUES ($id,'$filename') ";
    if(move_uploaded_file($filetmpname , $folder)){
         echo "<p color='green'>moved</p>";
         $qry = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         if($qry){
            echo "<p color='green'>Inserted into mysql</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p color='red'>Failed to Insert</p>";
        }
     }
     else {
         echo "<p style='color:red;'>Failed to move</p>";
    }

}
?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="id">
        <input type="file" name="uploadfile" />
        <input type="submit" name="uploadfilesub" value="upload" />
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that.

Comment: yeah Thank You , but I know that this is just for Image uploading test. that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see your error (in regards to the particular, mentioned, issue) is very simple:

```php
$folder = './Resources/style/images/';
```

change to:

```php
$folder = './Resources/style/images/' . $filename;
```

Simply `move_uploaded_file` expects full target path and not only target folder.

Comment: I tried this one also but it is not working. I edited my question check plz my code is just the same above

Comment: hmm, i have actually run your code (without the sql parts) and it works so the only problem remaining must be the path: try checking that by using `var_dump(is_dir('./Resources/style/images/'));` and also if it is writable: `var_dump(is_writable('./Resources/style/images/'));`. If it returns FALSE then the problem is with the path. You can check the working path of your script by calling `var_dump(getcwd());`

Comment: Thank You Your Solution Worked. Problem is with my directory privileges.